# Why $\operatorname{rank}(C)=r<n$ means that there are $r-n$ vectors vertical to every column of $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, control-theory

So I am studying a solved example we did in control systems class but I struggle a little bit with the linear algebra involved:
We are given a system (S), $x \in R^n and   A: n \times n$ that:
$ (S) = \begin{cases}
xA=Ax \\
xB=0\\
\end{cases}$
has only **{one solution}** : $x=0$

And we are asked to show that $(A,B)$ is controllable. (For anyone who doesn't know control theory: in simple terms we need to show that $rank(C)=n$ where $C=[B$ $ AB ... A^{n-1}B]$ "the controllabillity matrix".)
Solution)
We calculate : $xC = [xB$ $xA^2B$ $....$ $xA^{n-1}B]$ so it is a matrix with terms : $xA^{j-1}B$ with $j \in [0,n]$. If we take a closer look:
$xA^{j-1}B = AxA^{j-2}B= A^2xA^{j-3}B= .. = A^{j-1}xB = 0 $
**The part I am getting confused is when he said that:**
Let's suppose that $rank(C)= r<n$ , then there are $(n-r)$ $u_i$ , $i \in [1,n-r]$ vectors $\in R^n$ vertical to every column of $C$. If I create, a matrix $x$ that it's rows are these vectors: $x = \Big[\begin{cases}  u_1^T\\
u_2^T\\
. \\ . \\ . \\
U_{n-r}^T\\
\end{cases}$
then we reach a non- true conculsion therefore $rank(C)=n$.
**I need some more insight into how he concluded that:**

1. How he concuded that "then there are $(n-r)$ $u_i$ , $i \in [1,n-r]$ vectors $\in R^n$ vertical to every column of $C$" ?
   I thought that if $rank(C)=r<n$ then there must be $(n-r)$ linearly dependent columns( vectors) in $C$, which means that we can find a set of coefficients $a_i \neq 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n ai*ci = 0$ where $c_i$ an element of $C$.
   Is it a theorem that he uses? If anyone can suggest me what to study..?
2. Ok, let's say I understand 1, then we have built a matrix x with these vertical vectors such that $xC=0$ so he says that: $x \neq 0$ and $x$ satisfies the $(S)$ so we reached that the sytems does not have singular solution which isn't true?

Comment: If the rank of $C$ is $r < n$, then the dimension of the column space of $C$ is $r < n$, so the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus  \text{col} C$ is $n-r$. We know that this space is perpendicular to the column space, so with the dimension we can find $n - r$ vectors that are perpendicular to the column space (and are linearly independent of each other).

Comment: Just one tiny thing I cannot seem to follow: if $x\in R^n$, then this means $x$ is a column vector with $n$ rows, right? If so, one can compute the matrix multiplication of $Ax$, but not $xA$ (dimension mismatch).